# How to run a program in another user's terminal server (RDS) session

Tags: windows, terminal, remote-desktop

When I search this I mostly get results like "run a command as a different user" which is not what I'm looking for. I want to do something like psexec or runas, but not limited to that, but the point is for the program I run to run in the other user's session. I will not know their credentials.

In this specific case I am trying to run a script to reset the windows positions of a multi-window application that they are running in their own RDP session. They are running the app in seamless mode and have no way to go to a start menu or command prompt. I would use /shadow but since the application is seamless it gives me no more access to the start menu or command prompt that what the user has, which is none. I have the script set up as a remoteapp that normally works and the user can run it as a separate RDP connection, which will automatically connect to their active session so it acts on the other application running in that session, but sometimes it doesn't work.

I am really looking for a way to invoke a command within another user's RDP session which I could use for the case I described and maybe other situations in the future.

Comment: What about a login script?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It was a good one for the example I gave. I will clarify my question.